# Creating/Saving an inline base64 encoded image

Tags: php, image, base64, gd

I am trying to create & save images from data in an email from the base64 data of an actual image that was in the html body that appears inline such as:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAE==">
```

But i'm trying to create them sequentially, as there could be more than one image tag in the html body, where the variable $html_part is the html body of the email.
I just need some assistance in coming to a solution on what i'm doing wrong.

```
    $img_tags = preg_match('/<img\s+(.*)>/', $html_part, $num_img_tags);
    $num_img_tags = count($num_img_tags);

    echo $html_part;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_img_tags; $i++) {       
    preg_match('/<img\s+(.*)\s+src="data:image\/(.*);(.*),(.*)"\s+(.*)>/i', $html_part, $srcMatch);
{   
    foreach($srcMatch[4] as $im_data)
    {
        $ufname = "image0".$num_img_tags.".jpg";
        echo "<h1>$ufname</h1>";
            $im_data = base64_decode($im_data);
            $im = imagecreatefromstring($im_data);
            if ($im !== false) {
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg($im, $ufname);
            imagedestroy($im);
            }
            else {
            echo 'An error occurred.';
            }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is impossible - you cannot do a header() call after you've performed **ANY** output. You can also not output multiple images in the same 'document'. You also cannot output html (the `<h1>` stuff), images (`header('Content-type:...')`, etc... all within the same document.

As well, parsing/processing HTML with regexes is dangerous. A single malformation of the source document and your regexes will happily feast on garbage and produce garbage for you. Do not use regexes on html... every time you do, Alan Turing kills a kitten. Use a [DOM parser](http://php.net/dom) instead.

Comment: The header and `<h1>` stuff aren't in the final output, they are just lines i absentmindedly forgot to exclude for the example. I understand your plight regarding the danger of using regexes, but now that we are here, can you help me find a solution?

Comment: And the code isn't "impossible", it would almost work, just throw some errors.  imagejpeg($im, $ufname); doesn't send to browser, it writes it to a file, so it's one html output, multiple file saves, and a misguided header.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you want to use a preg_match_all, not a preg_match

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Also, solution using the above.

```
<?php

$html_part=<<<END
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAAVFBMVEWcZjTcViTMuqT8/vzcYjTkhhTkljT87tz03sRkZmS8mnT03tT89vTsvoTk1sz86uTkekzkjmzkwpT01rTsmnzsplTUwqz89uy0jmzsrmTknkT0zqT3X4fRAAAAbklEQVR4XnXOVw6FIBBAUafQsZfX9r/PB8JoTPT+QE4o01AtMoS8HkALcH8BGmGIAvaXLw0wCqxKz0Q9w1LBfFSiJBzljVerlbYhlBO4dZHM/F3llybncbIC6N+70Q7OlUm7DdO+gKs9gyRwdgd/LOcGXHzLN5gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAAVFBMVEWcZjTcViTMuqT8/vzcYjTkhhTkljT87tz03sRkZmS8mnT03tT89vTsvoTk1sz86uTkekzkjmzkwpT01rTsmnzsplTUwqz89uy0jmzsrmTknkT0zqT3X4fRAAAAbklEQVR4XnXOVw6FIBBAUafQsZfX9r/PB8JoTPT+QE4o01AtMoS8HkALcH8BGmGIAvaXLw0wCqxKz0Q9w1LBfFSiJBzljVerlbYhlBO4dZHM/F3llybncbIC6N+70Q7OlUm7DdO+gKs9gyRwdgd/LOcGXHzLN5gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
END;

preg_match_all('/<img.*?src="data:image\/.*;.*,(.*)".*?>/i', $html_part, $img_tags, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

echo $html_part;
$img_num = 0;
foreach($img_tags[1] as $im_data)
{
    $ufname = "image0".$img_num.".jpg";
    echo "<h1>$ufname</h1>";
    $im_data = base64_decode($im_data);
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($im_data);
    if ($im !== false) {
        imagejpeg($im, $ufname);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
    else {
        echo 'An error occurred.';
    }
    $img_num++;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but i receive a `Warning: imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: Empty string or invalid image` error, any ideas as to what can be causing this?

Comment: Also, i'm testing with an email with 3 images in the body, and even though the all the img tags in the body has the same base64 data, only the second image gets created and the first and third give off the above error.

Comment: I would suggest doing a var_dump of $img_tags and make sure its capturing the tags correctly